# How to target Microsoft.NetCore.App v1.0.3

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to deploy an Asp.net Core app to my shared host. Apparently, the server is only compatible with NetCore.App v1.03 or v.1.1.0, not the latest versions v1.0.4/v1.1.1 respectively. In Visual Studio, Im trying to publish to target framework "netcoreapp1.0" but I am only able to access NetCore.App v1.04 from Nuget. Nuget states that other versions including v1.0.3 are blocked by the project.

Can anyone tell me how to tell Visual Studio to use v1.0.3 for my project instead of v1.0.4?

[image]

Comment: You know that you don't have to deploy a portable app but you can also deploy a [self-contained app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd)? It will deploy the runtime (only runtime components which are really used by your application) with the application

Answer (score 0):

Apart from installing the missing versions on the server, you can add this manually to a `<PropertyGroup>` element of your `csproj` file:

```
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```